# Apply coupon for first purchase!

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon

Its possible to apply a coupon, in to the first purchase for new customers?

i don't know where is the option to apply coupon the first purchase.

[image]

Its possible? or i need some extension?

Comment: There is no such option at where youa re pointing at.

Answer (score 0):

> This can be possible approach, create a customer group, assign the
>   group as a default so the group will be assigned to new customers.
>   Then select a shopping cart price rule by selecting customer group,you
>   have created.

Follow the below steps.

1. Create a new customer group, add it as a default as below.

**System menu > Configuration >** Customer Configuration button in the Customers section on the left > Create New Account Options panel on the right > Default Group drop-down menu. Select the group that you want from the drop-down menu and click on the Save Config button.

2. Create Shopping Cart Price Rule for the customer group you have created.

   1. Select customer group.(You have created)
   2. Uses per Customer = 1
   3. Coupon = Specific Coupon
   4. Coupon Code = whatever you want.

One more possibility [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031011/magento-ce-discount-on-first-order)